# What is the meaning of content: "/\00a0" in the bootstrap breadcrumb CSS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I see this in the CSS

```
.breadcrumb > li + li:before {
padding: 0 5px;
color: #ccc;
content: "/\00a0";
}
```

Can someone explain what it means and how it works.

I have my code like this:

```
        <li>
            <a href="xxx">
                Home
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">xxx</li>
```

How could I implement the same thing without using the CSS. Can I just add a "/" in between the two `<li>` ? I tried adding a `<span>/</span>` but it says I cannot have a span inside the li.

Comment: Thanks - I see now the 00a0 is a code for a non-breaking space. But what exactly is a non breaking space?

Comment: A non-breaking space renders as a space but is considered a non-whitespace character by all word-wrapping display formatterrs (that's the theory at least ... ;-))

Comment: [Non breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) is the same as `&nbsp;`.

Comment: [In word processing and digital typesetting, a non-breaking space (" "), also known as a no-break space or non-breakable space (NBSP), is a variant of the space character that prevents an automatic line break (line wrap) at its position.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\00a0 is a nonbreakable space.

Comment: Thanks - If I wanted to implement this without CSS. How could I do this? Can I just put a "/" in between the <li> ?

Comment: See this: http://jsfiddle.net/6k2njm18/3/